# Performance monitoring is not working in sentry-expo

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I want to set up Performance monitoring for my react native app. I have used the below code for in app.js.

```
import * as Sentry from 'sentry-expo'

  Sentry.init({
    dsn: config.sentry,
    enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
    integrations: [
        new Sentry.Native.ReactNativeTracing({
          tracingOrigins: ['localhost', 'http://xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ngrok.io', /^\//, /^http:\/\//],
        }),
      ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0
  })
```

This is my sentry-expo version

```
"sentry-expo": "^4.0.5",
```

Still, it is not working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using real build (testflight/appstore and standalone android/google play app), or Expo Go?

Comment: I am using Expo Go. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

### Eliminate problems with Sentry

First of all, please check if you are able to receive exceptions from Expo Go. This can be done easily by code similar to this:

```
try {
 // Some code that throw new Error('error')
} catch (e) {
   Sentry.Native.captureException(e)
}
```

You should see log of this exception on your Sentry page (might take a few minutes to show up). By this, you eliminate issues with Sentry settings and can focus solely on tracing.

If you see the exception, you are good to go to make tracing work. If you don't see the exception, I recommend you to add `debug: true` into your `Sentry.init` in dev mode (it will print problems with Sentry SDK into console).

### Tracing

I believe you are missing Navigation Instrumentation in your code. Look at https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/performance/instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation/, especially at these code snippets (the code is modified by me so that it match React Native as the code provided in official documentation is not accurate):

```
// App.tsx
// Sentry for logging events from app 
// Construct a new instrumentation instance. This is needed to communicate between the integration and React

const routingInstrumentation = new Sentry.Native.ReactNavigationInstrumentation();

Sentry.init({
   dsn: config.sentry,
   enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
   integrations: [
      new Sentry.Native.ReactNativeTracing({
            routingInstrumentation // <-- Add this. I've deleted your origins settings to keep code more simple, it should work without it, feel free to add it back
         }),
      ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0 // this is required, but lower it in production
  })

// rest of App.tsx

export default Sentry.Native.wrap(App) <-- wrap export
```

And last part - modify `NavigationContainer` (assuming you are using `@react-navigation/native`, should be similar for other providers):

```
// Your app navigator
// My app navigator is not in App.tsx, so I am giving it in props
<NavigationContainer
   ref={navigationRef}
   // This line is probably new for you
   onReady={() => {
    props.navigationInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigationRef);
   }}
      {...props}
    >
      <AppStack />
</NavigationContainer>
```

After adding these part of code, you should see messages like this in your console when using Expo Go:

```
Sentry Logger [log]: [TouchEvents] Touch event within element: Score, tab, 3 of 4
```

And that's it!

### Last thing to check

It seems there is another issue with Sentry and Expo recently - version incompatibility. Check this thread: https://github.com/expo/sentry-expo/issues/243 for solution.

I am using `Expo 46` with `sentry-expo 4.2.0` and the combination works for me.

Comment: For React Navigation >5 it looks like you need to use `routingInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigatorRef);` in the NavigationContainer instead of `props.navigationInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigationRef);`